# Integrating Power BI with Qualys dashboards

Tags: powerbi, qualys

Is there a way to replicate specific dashboards set up in Qualys (with all the widgets visualising data) in Power BI? I have read through the forums and couldn't find anything about it. In general, I'm having trouble connecting to Qualys endpoints. There's no HOST_LIST column as outlined in [this Qualys support article](https://qualys.my.site.com/discussions/s/article/000003446).

[image: Here's what it returns in my Power Query Editor].

Also, connecting as described in the article (using From Web > Advanced and so on) just gave me a "We couldn’t authenticate with the credentials provided", even when I connected as Anonymous, so the only workaround was to paste the above into a blank query.

Anyone have any experience with this? Qualys's support just refers me to Power BI community threads, which don't really help...

Answer (score 0):

I have been working on this as well. Two thoughts:

1. Your API URL - is that correct for you? There are three of them for the EU and it would match with the regular Qualys platform URL you use. https://www.qualys.com/platform-identification/
2. Qualys data via API contains nested tables, so once you're connected, that's the challenge to work through. It's not like a flat CSV report download via the Qualys UI.

Instead of a screenshot to show you, I just made a quick YouTube video to show you how I connect and drill into the nested tables, and this way others can benefit too if they need help.

Here is the link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6J-AES7L5eA